# How do I use the confirmation dialog?

Tags: angular, kendo-scheduler

I have a kendo schedule which has the x button on the top right and which runs the code behind. I want to be able to manage the results from the confirmation dialog which appears when I add in reactive editing.

The Kendo-scheduler has `[kendoSchedulerReactiveEditing]="createFormGroup"` will popup a confirmation dialog when I hit the X.  However, the `(remove)="removeHandler($event)"` which is also on the scheduler is called the second I hit the X button.
Is there any way I can call removeHandler when I choose the "delete" on the confirmation dialog.

Comment: I get the dialog twice when I add the following to the removeHandler 
sender.openRemoveConfirmationDialog().subscribe((shouldRemove) => {
            if (shouldRemove) {
                // remove
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was mixing up two techniques.  My solution was to remove `[kendoSchedulerReactiveEditing]="createFormGroup"` and to have the following:

```
public removeHandler({ sender, dataItem }: RemoveEvent): void {
    sender.openRemoveConfirmationDialog().subscribe((shouldRemove) => {
        console.log('shouldRemove: ' + shouldRemove);
        if (shouldRemove) {
            // this.editService.remove(dataItem);
        }
    });
}
```